# Equilibrium on a fixed wedge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, equilibrium

While solving a question I came acrross this doubt.For a block in equilibrium on an inclined wedge, the summation of forces should be equal to zero.I am confused because I got two different results from the equation. Here[image: enter image description here].[1]]

Please let me know what is wrong, and what am I missing conceptually. Thanks.

Comment: While I can see why someone would vote to close as homework, this question seems fair enough to me. It's asking about how and why we equate forces, not just for an answer, and I recall being confused about this myself back in the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your second diagram:

[image: Normal force]

We know that the block doesn't move normal to the plane, so that means the net force normal to the plane must be zero i.e.

$$ N - mg\cos\theta = 0 $$

Now take your first diagram:

[image: Vertical force]

We know the block moves in a vertical direction because it slides down the slope. That means the net force in the vertical direction cannot be zero. Specifically we know the downward force must be greater than the upwards force:

$$ mg - N\cos\theta > 0 $$

Answer (score 1):

Well, first notice that neither of the diagrams shows all of the forces acting on the blocks because in neither of the diagrams can the vector forces shown sum to zero. In both cases there is also a frictional force vector which is acting in a direction normal to the inclined plane towards the upper right direction. With this 4th force vector all of the vectors can sum to zero in both the first diagram and the second diagram.

When you consider the inclusion of this 4th vector, then in your first diagram your argument of equating $N \cos\theta$ with $mg$ doesn't work because you also need to include a component of the frictional force vector into the equation. However, in your second diagram, equating $N$ with $mg \cos\theta$ is still valid because the frictional force vector is perpendicular to both the $\vec{N}$ and $m\vec{g}\cos\theta$ vectors and so the frictional force doesn't come into play in affecting the force balance along that direction. So $mg\cos\theta=N$ is the correct equation to describe the normal force $N$.

It's also apparent that something is wrong with the first equation by inspection: If you set $\theta$ to almost 90˚, then the the first equation implies that $N$ approaches infinity, whereas the second equation correctly implies that $N$ approaches zero.